# Is there any android support for bicycle sensors?

Tags: sensors, fitness

I've seen some Bluetooth Smart (4.0) technology for tracking tire rotation rate (bike speed), peddle rotation rate (cadence) and even heart rate monitors.

Some heart rate monitors are supported by google mytracks now.

Anybody aware of support for cycling sensors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not aware, but a quick check in the playstore shows there are several bicycle apps supporting "ANT+ sensors" for speed and other things. Take e.g. a look at [IpBike ANT+™ Bike Computer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iforpowell.android.ipbike), [ANT+ Bike Display Demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dsi.ant.bikepowerdemo), [IpBikeKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iforpowell.android.ipbikekey), and others. Starting point: [ANT+ Playstore search](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ant%2B-sensor+OR+ant%2B-bike+OR+ant%2B-bicycle&c=apps) :)

Please note that, as Ifor pointed out [in his comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40434/is-there-any-android-support-for-bicycle-sensors/40442#comment54872_40442), that this requires special support from the Android device's hardware. Details can be found e.g. at the [IpBike page](http://www.iforpowell.com/cms/index.php?page=ipbike).

Comment: nice , hadn't heard of ant + before!

Comment: Neither did I :)

Comment: You will need a phone with built in ANT support or a USB ANT stick and OTG cable.  I have some details on the web page for my app IpBike web page at http://www.iforpowell.com/cms/index.php?page=ipbike

Comment: Thank you for this useful details, @Ifor! As you can see above, the entire ANT+ thing is new to both of us, so I suppose we both were not aware of the need for special support from the Android device's hardware -- good thing to know! I hope you don't mind if I include that details with my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately USB host mode on my galaxy i9000 would take considerable hacking, but good to know for future in any case. people seem very happy with the USB ANT stick on galaxy s3s.